# Python Encryption/Decryption Failed

Tags: python, encryption

I am attempting to decrypt an encrypted message using a public/private key pair. When running my Python code, I am receiving a "ValueError: Encryption/decryption failed" error. Public/Private keys are both .pem and the encrypted message is .etxt. According to assignment instructions, "You may assume that one of the standard padding libraries is used. If your library instance requires you to provide padding, set it equal to an empty string."

Here is my complete code.  (error begins on line 25)

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding, rsa

# Load the public key
with open('C:/Users/bensg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/milestone_2_dataset/public_key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        key_file.read(),
        backend=None
    )

# Load the private key
with open('C:/Users/bensg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/milestone_2_dataset/private_key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=None
    )

# Load the encrypted message
with open('C:/Users/bensg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/milestone_2_dataset/emessage.etxt', 'rb') as file:
    encrypted_message = file.read()

# Decrypt the message using the private key
decrypted_message = private_key.decrypt(
    encrypted_message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)

print(decrypted_message.decode())
```

Here is the full traceback that I am receiving.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bensg\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    decrypted_message = private_key.decrypt(
  File "C:\Users\bensg\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py", line 444, in decrypt
    return _enc_dec_rsa(self._backend, self, ciphertext, padding)
  File "C:\Users\bensg\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py", line 95, in _enc_dec_rsa
    return _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx(backend, key, data, padding_enum, padding)
  File "C:\Users\bensg\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py", line 161, in _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx
    raise ValueError("Encryption/decryption failed.")
ValueError: Encryption/decryption failed.
```

I am not a very experienced coder and I am stuck up to this point. I believe it has something to do with my decryption method in line 25, but I do not know any steps or alternative options, which is why I am making this post! I am new to this community so if I am posting incorrectly, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure that OAEP with SHA-256 (for both digests) was used during encryption? Note, if the padding is different, decryption will fail. *...You may assume that one of the standard padding libraries is used. If your library instance requires you to provide padding, set it equal to an empty string...* suggests that you don't know exactly which padding was used for encryption.

Comment: @Topaco I am not sure... are there a finite number of other options that would be considered "standard padding libraries" that I can attempt to use?

Comment: If you don't know the padding, you have to contact the encrypting side. Alternatively, you can try to find the padding by trial and error. RSA applies two paddings PKCS#1 v1.5 and OAEP. The latter uses various parameters, e.g. digests, which you would have to try out (often SHA-1 or SHA-256 are applied). Can you post the encryption code or sample data (*test* key, ciphertext)?

Comment: The library you are using is not really low level enough to perform raw RSA encryption. I'd switch to e.g. a pure python implementation of RSA, decrypt, and then find out that the padding is likely PKCS#1v1.5 ;) That hint is also in the assignment. The PKCS#1 standard clearly defines some byte values for the different kind of paddings that you should be able to recognize.

Comment: @Topaco After playing around with PKCS#1 v1.5 for a bit, I returned to my original code and swapped SHA-256 to SHA-1 and sure enough, it works! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction